# Convert from BINARY directly to INT, bypassing intermediate CHAR

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm converting a table that has a column storing integers as hexadecimal strings.  I'd like to convert these strings to integers, as they take up less space and are easier to query.  However, it seems that MySQL lacks an efficient way to convert from BINARY to INT.

This works:

```
SELECT CAST(CONV(some_column, 16, -10) AS SIGNED);
-- some_column = "49858170ef9a4f63"
```

...but it converts to a decimal string first, which is less than ideal.  I'd like to convert directly to an integer, bypassing the string:

```
SELECT CONVERT(UNHEX(some_column), SIGNED);
-- some_column = "49858170ef9a4f63"
```

...but it doesn't work; I always get 0.  It seems to be doing the same thing as CAST.

How can I convert a BINARY value directly to an INT, without first converting it to a string?  In a more abstract sense, how can I change the type of a value without changing the underlying data?

Note that this is purely MySQL; I am not using PHP or any other scripting language.

Comment: I misread the tag and retracted the vote to close

Answer (score 0):

Short of creating your own `STORED FUNCTION`, I don't think there is way you can avoid converting to a string first.

I am guessing UNHEX is not working because (at least MySQL's official example suggests), HEX/UNHEX convert the string/decimal bytes to/from a hex characters representation, and your hex strings are probably of the '0x???' format, which CONVERT will change to '0'.

Given `CONV` has to parse the string anyway, I doubt it converting it to a decimal string really requires that much additional overhead.

Comment: Try `SELECT UNHEX(some_column), CONVERT(UNHEX(some_column), SIGNED);` to see what you are actually trying to cast to an integer. `234adf` comes back as `#Jß`; MySQL will try it's best to convert any string to integer, it stops when it hits it's first non-decimal character, meaning that string will be effectively '0'. Running it through MySQL Workbench confirms quickly that it is using byte values {23, 4a, df} for the result.

Comment: Right, I want to create an integer out of the raw bytes.  I don't want to parse the string.  MySQL is trying to be smart when I don't want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

To `INT`

```
conv(substr(hex(segment), -8)
```

TO `ip addr`

```
SELECT INET_NTOA(conv(substr(hex(segment), -8), 16, 10))
```

Good luck.

Comment: The input is already in hex. I'm looking to go from hex or binary to an integer without generating an entirely new string in the process.